# How to reverse the order of letters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, functional-programming

In python, how do you reverse the order of words in a string and also reverse the order of the letters in the word.

For example, if the input is:

```
Hello world
```

The output should be:

```
olleH dlrow
```

My attempt:

```
a=input('Line: ') 
print(a[::-1])
```

Comment: so if the input is 'hello world' the output is 'dlorw olleh'. However the code output should be 'olleh dlrow'.

Comment: OP's problem is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375794/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-words-in-a-string-in-python since they wish to reverse the order of the words as well. Please disregard my duplicate flag.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output conflicts with the description of your requirements viz "how do you reverse the order of words in a string and also reverse the order of the letters in the word.". That would simply be the same as reversing the string, which you have already provided as your solution. Instead, to reverse the the letters in each word, but retain the order of those words, you can use `split()` and a reverse slice (`[::-1]`) on each word.

```
s = "Hello world"
for word in s.split():
    print word[::-1],
```

Or, like this:

```
print ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in s.split())
```

The above assumes that you do not need to retain the exact whitespace between words.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using the [slice option](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
def reverseOrder(strs):
return ''.join([strs[i] for i in xrange(len(strs)-1, -1, -1)])
```

or better try this:

```
>>> s='Hello World'
>>> ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
'olleH dlrow'
```

Comment: i am able to do that part of the question, however the output needs to be 'olleH dlrow' not 'dlrow olleH'